# Stop automatically button resizing in MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm working in WPF MVVM. I have two buttons that are included in a grid, the grid is included in a viewBox and the viewBox in a Window. When I maximize the window I don't want the buttons' size to rise. My question is: can I manage this from XAML code ?

Those properties are set for the buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="openButton" Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Padding="0.1" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"/>
<Button x:Name="closeButton" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Padding="0.1" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set either the Height to the button or to the row that contains it. For instance:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinition>
       <RowDefinition Height = "Auto"/>
       <RowDefinition Height = "Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinition>
   <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="openButton" Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Padding="0.1" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"/>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="closeButton" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Padding="0.1" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>  
</Grid>
```

Setting the Height of a row to auto mean that the size will adjust based on the row content; since buttons by default have an height that should be of 25 pixel, if you don't bound them inside a container, this size will growth accordingly to the size of the window. Also you need to assign the Grid.Row property in your buttons. In my example i've defined 2 rows that stack the buttons vertically, but you can define one row and 2 columns to stack them horizontally